How to dynamically convert a dataframe from one schema to another with struct types of the same name?
I'm trying to convert a PySpark data frame to a similar one that contains struct fields. I have tried a recursive approach but cannot obtain the output structure.
In a simple way:
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Row

schema_in = StructType([
    StructField("name",StringType(),True),
    StructField("age",LongType(),True),
    StructField("manager",StructType([
                          StructField("manager_name",StringType(),True),
                          StructField("manager_age",LongType(),True)]),True),
    StructField("manager_city",StringType(),True),
    StructField("manager_dept",StringType(),True)])
    
schema_out = StructType([
    StructField("name",StringType(),True),
    StructField("age",LongType(),True),
    StructField("manager",StructType([
                          StructField("manager_name",StringType(),True),
                          StructField("manager_age",LongType(),True),
                          StructField("detail",StructType([
                                               StructField("manager_city",StringType(),True),
                                               StructField("manager_dept",StringType(),True)]),True)]),True)])                                                                  

data = [
    Row("Alex", 20, Row("Bob",30),"Madrid","Supply Chain"),
    Row("Cathy", 40, Row("Doge",40),"Barcelona","Human Resources")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema_in)
df.printSchema()
df.show(20,False)

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- manager: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- manager_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- manager_age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- manager_city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- manager_dept: string (nullable = true)

+-----+---+----------+------------+---------------+
|name |age|manager   |manager_city|manager_dept   |
+-----+---+----------+------------+---------------+
|Alex |20 |{Bob, 30} |Madrid      |Supply Chain   |
|Cathy|40 |{Doge, 40}|Barcelona   |Human Resources|
+-----+---+----------+------------+---------------+

df2=df.withColumn('manager', f.col('manager')\
.withField('detail', f.struct(*[f.col('manager_city').alias('manager_city'), f.col('manager_dept').alias('manager_dept')])))\
.drop ("manager_city")\
.drop ("manager_dept")
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(20,False

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- manager: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- manager_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- manager_age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- detail: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- manager_city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- manager_dept: string (nullable = true)

+-----+---+----------------------------------------+
|name |age|manager                                 |
+-----+---+----------------------------------------+
|Alex |20 |{Bob, 30, {Madrid, Supply Chain}}       |
|Cathy|40 |{Doge, 40, {Barcelona, Human Resources}}|
+-----+---+----------------------------------------+

What I'm trying to do is that it dynamically generates the data frame with the output desired schema, counting with already having input fields, so it can serve for any dataframe and output schema, providing output fields previously existing on the input data frame.
I got something close to the solution using this method, but I cannot figure out where the problem is (my recursivity is not any good :( ):

def arrange_fields(df_in, schema_out):
    def add_new_fields(schema, prefix=""):

        columnas = []
        for field in schema.fields:
            field_name = f"{prefix}.{field.name}" if prefix else field.name
            
            if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
                nested_columns = add_new_fields(field.dataType, field_name)
                if prefix:
                    existing_struct = col(prefix)
                    columnas.append(struct(*nested_columns, existing_struct).alias(field.name))
                else:
                    columnas.append(struct(*nested_columns).alias(field.name))
            else:

                if field.name in df_in.columns:
                    columnas.append(col(field.name).alias(field.name))
        return columnas

    columnas = add_new_fields(schema_out)
    return df_in.select(*columnas)

df_transformed = arrange_fields(df_in, schema_out)
df_transformed.printSchema()
df_transformed.show(truncate=False)

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- manager: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- detail: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- manager_city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- manager_dept: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- manager: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- manager_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- manager_age: long (nullable = true)

+--------+---+----------------------------------+
|name    |age|manager                           |
+--------+---+----------------------------------+
|John Doe|30 |{{New York, HR, {Jane Smith, 45}}}|
+--------+---+----------------------------------+


The code updates the struct field, but it adds an additional nesting level for the manager field that does not match the desired output schema.

with Spark 3.1.0+, you can use expressions associated with pyspark.sql.Column (withField and dropFields) to manipulate the StructType() columns. in your example, you can do: df_transformed = df.withColumn('manager', f.col('manager').withField('details', f.struct('manager_city','manager_dept'))).drop('manager_city','manager_dept') , no need to do extra work.
